# Swift Extra argument in call

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I'm having trouble calling a specific method on my Swift project. Here's the ObjC method signature:

```
- (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder options:(SDWebImageOptions)options completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock;
```

I can't put this to work as XCode keeps telling me "Extra argument 'placeholderImage' in call"

```
self.lastLookImageView.setImageWithURL(url,
    placeholderImage: nil,
    options: SDWebImageRefreshCached,
    completed: {
       (image, error, cacheType) -> Void in
       image = image.blurredImageWithRadius(30, iterations: 2, tintColor: UIColor.clearColor())
    }
)
```

XCode doesn't even recognize the method when I Cmd+Click on it: "Symbol not found".

I suspect it has something todo with the block, because I can call other method of this same class, which is almost identica, but without the completion block. Working example:

```
self.lastLookImageView.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: self.lastLook!.image), placeholderImage: nil, options: SDWebImageRefreshCached)
```

For context sake: I'm using a component called SDWebImage (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) on my mixed Obj-C and Swift project. The class is already imported on my Bridging-Header.h

Comment: Where is the `forState` paramater and why is there a `completed ` parameter tucked on the end?

Comment: The completion handler exists and it's on the H file (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIImageView%2BWebCache.h#L129)

Comment: I've edited the question to include the signature I was talking about. sorry

Answer (score 1):

The Swift method signature should be:

```
func setImageWithURL(url: NSURL!, forState state: UIControlState,
            placeholderImage placeholder: UIImage! options: SDWebImageOptions)
```

So you'd need to call it with:

```
self.lastLookImageView.setImageWithURL(url, forState: .Normal, 
            placeholderImage: nil, options: SDWebImageRefreshCached)
```

There's no completion handler for this method, so leave that out.

Comment: Actually there is a method with completion handler: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIImageView%2BWebCache.h#L129